# Short circuit behavior of logical expressions in C in this example

Tags: c

PROGRAM

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;

    i = 1; j = 1; k = 1;

    printf("%d ", ++i || ++j && ++k);
    printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);

  return 0;
}
```

OUTCOME

```
1 2 1 1
```

I was expecting 1 1 2 2. Why? Because the && has precedence over ||. So I followed these steps:
1) j added 1, so j now values 2...
 2) k added 1, so k now values 2...
 3) 2 && 2, evaluates to 1...
 4) No need of further evaluation as the right operand of || is true, so the whole expression must be true because of short circuit behavior of logical expressions...

Why am I wrong?

Comment: This exercise is in my textbook, and according to it there is no undefined behaviour here.

Comment: That means you are reading a non-standard book.

Comment: @al-Acme: `||` and `&&` introduce sequence points.

Comment: @Mat - ahh was too quick in reading the question. :/

Comment: Please do not write this sort of code - it is difficult to read at best.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Precedence affects only the grouping. `&&` has a higher precedence than `||` means:

```
++i || ++j && ++k
```

is equivalent to:

```
++i || (++j && ++k)
```

But that doesn't mean `++j && ++k` is evaluated first. It's still evaluated left to right, and according to the short circuit rule of `||`, `++i` is true, so `++j && ++k` is never evaluated.

Comment: But if that is parenthesized, shouldn't that be evaluated first?

Comment: Short circuit - bit one left if left forget the rest

Comment: Shouldn't ++i print 2 instead of 1?

Comment: @Cool Guy `2 || anything` is equal to `1`

Comment: @mch , So the whole thing returns 1(true) and not the value of ++i?

Comment: @CoolGuy yes, the whole expression evaluates to 0 (false) or 1 (true).