# Logical operator | | in C

Tags: c

I'm struggling to understand the behavior of the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    i = 7;
    j = 8;
    k = 9;
    printf("%d\n", (i = j) || (j = k));
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k);

    return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
1
8, 8, 9
```

Question:

- I understand that *expr1* | | *expr2* has the value *1* if either *expr1* or *expr2*(or both)has a nonzero value.
- The value of *`i`* increased from `7` to `8` because `j`'s value is assigned to *`i`* but the same way why does the value of the `j` is not increased even though `j = k?` I was expecting an

output

```
1
8, 9, 9
```

Comment: The `||` is a short circuit operator meaning it won't evaluate the right half it not necessary, like in this case

Comment: `(i = j)` means you are assigning value of `j` to `i`. Are you trying to assign or compare? For comparison, use `==` operator instead.

Comment: I suggest a read on operator precedence.

Comment: [Short circuit behavior of logical expressions in C in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28145152/995714)

Comment: @Sorenp "operator precedence" is not relevant here, there is only one way to parse the code as written .  The issue is with short circuit evaluation

Comment: The short circuit behaviour can be used for error handling although generally not considered good style, e.g. `fread(b, 1, 500, fp) == 500 || printf("Read failed");`

Comment: @kiner_shah The OP already mentioned in the question that this is an assignment. The question is not why `i` is changed but why `j` is not.

Answer (score 5):

From the C standard (emphasis mine):

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the
> second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
> and second operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
> not evaluated.**

The above behaviour is commonly referred to as operator short circuiting.

In your example, since `(i = j)` is not zero the second operand is thus not evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all,

`true || true` is `true`

`true || false` is `true`

`false || true` is `true`

`false || false` is `false`

So operator `||` is calculating the first expression and if it is true, it does not check the second one.

In yours particular situation `(i = j)` is equal to 8, which is considered true, because int values are considered false only if they are equal 0.
So the second `(j = k)` is never computed, which leads to your result.

Comment: Thank you very much Bomber Cubit. I understand it now!